# Is shared WebAssembly.memory, SharedArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, sharedarraybuffer

Can we say that if the flag of WebAssembly.memory is true, it is precisely SahredArrayBuffer?

Comment: it really isn't clear what you are asking?

Comment: If we use webAssembly.memory with true shared flag, it works like sharedarraybuffer. My question is that can we say it is exactly sharedarraybuffer in this case or it is just something that works like sharedarraybuffer?

Comment: In browser it will be specifically `SharedArrayBuffer`, but it can be something else in other engines. You can't and shouldn't rely on these implementation details in your wasm code.